# How to absolutely stop the video from playing without the user interacting with it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, youtube-api, html5-video

I have a page that loads a random fetched video via an id, after a delay, lets say, 5  seconds, it redirects me to another page. This "other page" also does the same thing and loads the video but from a different playlist and then redirects the user back to the first page and so on and so forth. The problem is that on the second, and all the other redirects, the page loads a new video but doesnt stop the previoes one from playing. It feels like Ive tried everything at this point: I tried using the .pause() method on the video, I tried replacing the video with and empty div before redirecting, loading the videos by using the parameters from the url and implementing the context api(react) to reshuffle an array of preloaded videos and only display them one by one, i would really appreciate the help.
The index page:

```
function Index(props) {
 const items = usePlaylist('RDMM', 'AIzaSyCkhQc1Gu6kmb6pYcfArYo75WXgSs_5PFw');
 const { setItems, setCount, count } = useContext(PlaylistContext);
 const [itemID, setItemID] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
 if (items) {
 items.forEach((obj) => {
 const id = obj.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
 setItemID((prev) => {
 return [...prev, id];
        });
      });
    }
  }, [items]);

 const shuffledArray = itemID.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());
 setItems(shuffledArray);
 setCount(0);

 const playLink = shuffledArray ? (
 <Link to={`/play/${shuffledArray[count]}`}>caramel</Link>
  ) : (
 <div></div>
  );
 return <div>{playLink}</div>;
}
```

The first page that the user inittially gets redirected to:

```
function Player(props) {
 const player = new YouTubeToHtml5({
 autoplay: false,
 withAudio: true,
  });

 setTimeout(() => {
 player.load();
  }, 0);

 const { currentVid, setCurrentVid } = useContext(PlaylistContext);
 const history = useHistory();
 const videoRef = useRef(null);

 const { src } = useParams();
 console.log(videoRef);
 useEffect(() => {
 if (videoRef) {
 console.log(videoRef.current);
 console.log(videoRef.current.pause);
 setCurrentVid(videoRef.current);
 videoRef.current.pause();
 console.log('paused');
    }
  }, [videoRef]);
 setTimeout(() => {
 videoRef.current?.pause();
 history.push('/intermission');
  }, 5 * 1000);

 return (
 <>
 <Video ref={videoRef} id={src} />
 </>
  );
}
```

The second player page:

```
function Player(props) {
 var player = new YouTubeToHtml5({
 autoload: true,
 withAudio: true,
  });
 setTimeout(() => {
 player.load();
  }, 0);

 const history = useHistory();
 const { currentVid } = useContext(PlaylistContext);

 useEffect(() => {
 if (currentVid) {
 setTimeout(() => {
 console.log('ran stop');
 console.log(currentVid);
 currentVid.pause();
      }, 100);
    }
  }, [currentVid]);
 const intermission = setTimeout(() => {
 // history.push('/player');
 console.log('pushed');
  }, 15 * 1000);
 return (
 <>
 <Video id='BV7RkEL6oRc' />
 </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have a similar situation and for me calling `pause()` and setting `currentTime` to zero works. Make sure your code runs when you navigate to the other page.

Comment: I found what the issue was, I was setting the context inside of the component which was causing it to rerender, I fixed it by setting the `count` with localStorage and deleting the later implemented `setMute` function that was muting the video. Each time it updated the component, it also set a new timeout which was causing it to constantly rerun the callback function and basically causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the issue was, I was setting the context inside of the component which was causing it to rerender, I fixed it by setting the count with localStorage and deleting the later implemented setMute function that was muting the video. Each time it updated the component, it also set a new timeout which was causing it to constantly rerun the callback function and basically causing an infinite loop.